# grails log.info ${message i18n support?

Tags: grails

```
                //log.info "${message(code: 'default.mylabel.label', default: 'My Default output: $myVariable', args: [${message(code: 'ignore.myVariable.label', default: '$myVariable'})])}"
                //log.info "${g.message(code: 'default.mylabel.label', default: 'My Default output: '+myVariable, args: [myVariable])}"
                def ff="${message(code: 'default.mylabel.label', default: 'My Default output: ')}"

                log.info "${ff}"
```

I have tried a variety of things if I remove ${ then it returns the rest as string but whilst attempting to pass ${message through to log.info it returns this message i.e. not accepting a hashmap

```
    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[code:default.something.label, ...]]
```

Anyone know if there is a way of having i18n support within log.info calls?

**UPDATE**
This is a message being returned in main app, with the log.info being [pumped from a plugin](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/mailinglist/core/MailingListEmailService.groovy). I have made the page that this was attempted on as a link, with the above error message being returned to main app whilst running.

Comment: I think i found the answer injection of messageSource

Comment: that does not seem to be the solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Following is my log4j configuration in Config file and your code is working for me

```
log4j = {
appenders {
    rollingFile name: 'catalinaOut', maxFileSize: 1024, fileName: "catalina.out"
    file name: 'stacktrace', file: "catalina.out", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
}

environments {
    development {
        debug 'grails.app.controllers', 'stdout'
        debug 'grails.app.services'
    }
    production {
        root {
            debug 'grails.app', 'catalinaOut'
            debug 'grails.app', 'stdout'
            error 'catalinaOut'
            warn 'catalinaOut'
            info 'catalinaOut'
            additivity = true
        }
    }
}

error stacktrace: "StackTrace"

error 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
        'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

Comment: Will look over my log4j tomorrow, but very much doubt it relates to this due to the error being returned from grails. The other thing I have forgot to mention which I will update the question with is that this is within a plugin

Comment: ok stupid me, I moved the log4j config to external configuration, but I am currently testing the code on a test box which does not have log4j configuration defined at all so I guess this must be the issue, although since it has been logging in general was probably why it got missed

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably not worded correctly in the question is accessing i18n through services. The answer turned out to be this:

```
    import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder as LCH
        class MailingListEmailService {
        def messageSource

def someAction() { 
 log.info messageSource.getMessage('default.mylabel.label', ["${recipientToList}","${recipientToList}"].toArray(), "MY DEFAULT VALUE IF NOT DEFINED", LCH.getLocale())
}
        }
```

This is looking for the key called default.mylabel.label in my messages.properties file, it is passing the two variables which in this test was itself twice as an array followed by the default value to display if not found and finally the locale from which the site is running.

If you are flashing messages from services same thing but I guess you would need to pass through request.getLocale() since the message is going to user rather than log file for which server is running on...